# iPhone - sorting "10, 20, 30" the correct order with core data

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have a string field on an entity. Every time I want to retrieve a sort list of entries and the entries contain numbers, the list comes like this:

```
car 1
car 10
car 11
car 2
car 21
etc.
```

instead of

```
car 1
car 2
car 10
car 11
car 21
```

How do I force the request to sort the numbers correctly in a string property?

I am using this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortByItem =  [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:key ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByItem];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

thanks.

Comment: I think you have to write your own sort method. I don't know about any default sorting methods regarding this.

Comment: It is sorting the numbers correctly but it is sorting them on their ordinal value not their numerical value.  Can you load the values as integers into an NSMutableArray and then sort that?

Comment: can you change 1 into 01 in your sort method? that would do it. Like @"%02i"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your own comparison method that looks like this:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)numericCompare:(NSString *)aString
{
    return [self compare:aString options:NSNumericSearch];
}
```

Then pass this method's selector to the sort descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an easier way. Simply use localizedStandardCompare: instead of compare: and it sorts numbers on strings correctly.